# TypeError: Post.create is not a function for mongodb

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

test.js file contains `.create` function which on running shows the type error.
I have tried insert function save function but it does not identify it as a function at all. I cannot find out what is the type error here in create function.

**test.js** file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Post = ('/database/models/Post')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/nodejs-test-blog')

// Post.find({}, (error, posts) => {
//     console.log(error, posts)
//   })

Post.create({
  title: 'My second blog post',
  description: 'Second Blog post description',
  content: 'Second Lorem ipsum content.'
}, (error, post) => {
  console.log(error, post)
})
```

**Post.js** file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
///

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  description: String,
  content: String
})

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema)

module.exports = Post
```

Comment: You should include Post Modal into test.js and use it. If did it  const Post = require('/database/models/Post') ?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and post there full error message?

Answer (score 1):

Use defining schema path for mongodb

`require('./database/models/Post')`

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

```
require('./database/models/Post');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Post = mongoose.model('Post);
```

and if you have a lot of models you might want to create a different file and require all the models together and require this new file

### models.js

```
const glob = require('glob');
const path = require('path');

// grab all mongo models name to require them
glob.sync('./database/models/**/*.js').forEach(file => {
    require(path.resolve(file));
});
```

and then in your test.js file

```
require('./path/to/models.js');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Post = mongoose.model('Post);
```

Answer (score 0):

The object must be denoted while importing the schema. Try this.

```
const Post = ('/database/models/Post').Post;
```